# Finite Rank Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

actually I want to prove
Let $X$ be a Banach space. $T \in B(X)$ be a finite rank bounded linear operator. Then $$Tx= \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x) x_i$$ where $x_1,x_2 \ldots ,x_n$ from $X$  and $f_1,f_2 \ldots f_n$ from $X^\star$ are linearly independent.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want to prove this

Comment: Because $T$ is a finite rank operator its image has a finite basis $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and each $Tx$ for $x\in X$ has a unique representation $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_jx_j$ where $\alpha_j$ depends on $x$. Define $f_j$ by $f_j(x)=\alpha_j$ for $j=1,..,n$ and show that these are n linearly independent functionals.

Comment: how to get $f_j$ such that $f_j(x)= \alpha _j$ @ Peter Melech

Comment: You define the functions $f_j:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ this way and then show that they are linear, bounded and linearly independent

Comment: Is $f_{i}(x)$ dependent on the point $x\in X$ that you choose? The question is unclear!

Comment: I have proved $f_j$ are linear and linearly independent but I am unable to prove that they are bounded.please help me.@PeterMelech

Comment: Or is it that these $f_{i}$ are independent of the point $x$ chosen?

Comment: @PeterMelech Isn't the $f_{i}$ that you have suggested dependent on the particular point you choose?

Comment: @Riju No, they are not dependent on $x$. The basis $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is independent of $x$, and the function $f_j$ takes any $x$ and returns the $j$th coordinate under this basis.

Comment: @TheoBendit Are you sure? The $f_{i}$'s that are needed must belong to $X^{*}$. But $\{\ x_{1}, x_{2}, ... , x_{n} \}\ $ is a basis for $T(X)$ and not of whole $X$. So I think that you are saying that first define $f_{i}$ on $T(X)
$, by taking the dual basis of $x_{i}$'s, then extend these $f_{i}$'s to an element of $X^{*}$, by Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: No, you definitely define $f_i$ on $X$. The $f_i$ will certainly depend on $T$, but not on $x$. For **every** vector in $X$, the vector $T(x)$ can be expressed as a unique linear combination $f(x) = \alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots \alpha_n x_n$. The constants $\alpha_i$ depend on $x$, and all $f_i$ represents is this dependency. Sure it's an implicit definition of a function, but its construction depends on is $T$ and a basis for $T(X)$.

Comment: @Manu Rohilla On the finite dimensional space $T(X)$ all norms are equivalent, so there exists a constant $C$ such that for every $x\in X$ You have $|f_jx|=|\alpha_j|\leq \max_{i}|\alpha_i|\leq C ||Tx||_X\leq C||T|| ||x||_X$ where $||T||$ denotes the operator norm and the maximum norm with respect to the basis $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is equivalent to the norm induced by that on $X$